# can't change list of list for some reason. works in python 2 but not in python 3

Tags: python

```
board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"
```

doesn't work. "type error str does not support item assignment"

I can do it in python 2 but not 3. How do I change it to work with python 3.

here is the board setup

```
board = []

for i in range(5):
  board.append("O" * 5)
```

Comment: We really, really need more context.  What are `board`, `guess_row`, and `guess_col` supposed to be?  Can you show the results of printing out all three in both Python2 and Python3?

Comment: You can't replace a single character within a string.

Comment: Doesn't work in Python 2, either.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like one of
`guess_row`
or
`guess_col` is a string,

So it tries to modify a string in a certain position, thats not possible in Python3

Could you run `print(type(board[guess_row]))` and

`print(type(board[guess_row][guess_col]))` to make sure that they are an array.

Comment: there type is int

Comment: Whoops, made a mistake there, I edited my anwser, could you try again?

Comment: they are strings

Comment: Thats the problem, can you show the initalisation of the arrays?

Comment: i edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

i should have done

```
board = []

for x in range(5):
  board.append(["O"] * 5)
```

instead of

```
board = []

for x in range(5):
  board.append("O" * 5)
```